# Alfresco custom-selectone.ftl

Tags: javascript, alfresco, freemarker

I want to make my custom selectone.ftl. I am going step by step, so I created customselectone.ftl with constant values to return from javascript to ftl control. 
So, I have newCodes [c1,c2,c3] witch I want to be on my selectone list.

When I run Alfresco Share and start my action I get dialog with empty selectone, and result of alert(document.getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}")) is null. Why is that? I am using Alfresco 5.0.d version. 
I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

customselectone.ftl

```
<#assign controlId = fieldHtmlId + "-cntrl">
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var newCodes = ["c1", "c3", "c4"];
alert(document.getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}"));
alert(document.getElementById("${controlId}"));
var sel = document.getElementById(${fieldHtmlId});
alert(sel);
alert(newCodes);
for(var i = 0; i < newCodes.length; i++) {
alert('usao u petlju');
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = newCodes[i];
        opt.value = newCodes[i];
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }

//]]></script>


<div id="${controlId}" class="form-field">
<labelfor="${fieldHtmlId}">${msg("form.control.myoptions.label")}:<#if        field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>

<select id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="prop_${field.name}" tabindex="0"

   <#if field.description??>title="${field.description}"</#if>

   <#if field.control.params.size??>size="${field.control.params.size}"</#if> 

   <#if field.control.params.styleClass??>class="${field.control.params.styleClass}"</#if>

   <#if field.control.params.style??>style="${field.control.params.style}"</#if>>

</select>
<@formLib.renderFieldHelp field=field />
</div>
```

share-config-custom.xml

```
<!-- Custom Action Forms -->
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="changeDmsMonaType">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="docClass" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <field id="docClass" label-id="actions.dmsmona.changeDmsMonaType.docClass">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/customselectone.ftl">
                        </control>
                </field>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `alert(document.getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}"))` is executed before the HTML is completely rendered. So the `<select id="${fieldHtmlId}">` does not exist in the DOM tree when you call `getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}")`.

I think this is one reason why your code does not work.

Why do you use JavaScript anyway? You can do it in plain Freemarker:

```
<#assign controlId = fieldHtmlId + "-cntrl">
<#assign newCodes = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']>

<div id="${controlId}" class="form-field">
   <labelfor="${fieldHtmlId}">${msg("form.control.myoptions.label")}:<#if        field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>

<select id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="prop_${field.name}" tabindex="0"

   <#if field.description??>title="${field.description}"</#if>

   <#if field.control.params.size??>size="${field.control.params.size}"</#if> 

   <#if field.control.params.styleClass??>class="${field.control.params.styleClass}"</#if>

   <#if field.control.params.style??>style="${field.control.params.style}"</#if>>
   <#list newCodes as optionItem>
       <option value="${optionItem?html}>${optionItem?html}</option>
   </#list>
</select>
<@formLib.renderFieldHelp field=field />
</div>
```

**Edit**

If you want to use JavaScript (as stated in your comment), you can use either the `window.onload` or the `DOMContentLoaded` events.

`onload` has the drawback that it executes scripts only after the whole document including all external resources has been loaded. This might lead to delays that are percieved by the user as too long until the page actually fully works.

`DOMContentLoaded` has compatibility issues on some browsers (IE9 and older afaik).

For a solution you can use e.g. [ContentLoaded.js by Diego Perini](http://javascript.nwbox.com/ContentLoaded/contentloaded.js).

Your result could look like this:

```
<#assign controlId = fieldHtmlId + "-cntrl">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://javascript.nwbox.com/ContentLoaded/contentloaded.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function initializeDynamicContent() {
    var newCodes = ["c1", "c3", "c4"];
    alert(document.getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}"));
    alert(document.getElementById("${controlId}"));
    var sel = document.getElementById(${fieldHtmlId});
    alert(sel);
    alert(newCodes);
    for(var i = 0; i < newCodes.length; i++) {
        alert('usao u petlju');
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = newCodes[i];
        opt.value = newCodes[i];
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
contentLoaded(window, initializeDynamicContent);
//]]></script>

<div id="${controlId}" class="form-field">
    <labelfor="${fieldHtmlId}">${msg("form.control.myoptions.label")}:<#if field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>
    <select id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="prop_${field.name}" tabindex="0"
      <#if field.description??>title="${field.description}"</#if>
      <#if field.control.params.size??>size="${field.control.params.size}"</#if> 
      <#if field.control.params.styleClass??>class="${field.control.params.styleClass}"</#if>
      <#if field.control.params.style??>style="${field.control.params.style}"</#if>>
    </select>
    <@formLib.renderFieldHelp field=field />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the reason, I concluded it later.. I do it from Java Script because, later, I want to pass some dynamic values to Java Script and render it in Freemarker, it would not be ['c1', 'c2' , ' c3' ] than some dynamic array witch I will get from Java backed WebScript.

Comment: I was considering ready function, but there is not jQuery.. only pure JavaScript. Do you have some idea how can I do it? 
Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Amended my answer with JavaScript example.

Comment: Thnks Lars, it was really helpfull.